# Python SQLite3 fetch raw?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem with this code :

```
cur.execute('SELECT Balance FROM accounts')
print(cur.fetchone())
```

That outputs: `(0,)` instead of what I want `0`.

Can anyone help to fix the error? Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchone()` would return you a single table row which may contain multiple columns. In your case it is a single column value returned in a tuple. Just get it by index:

```
data = cur.fetchone()
print(data[0])
```

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there would be more than one value in your query, so it always returns a tuple (you wouldn't want an interface which changes depending upon the data you pass it would you?).

You can unpack the tuple:

```
value, = cur.fetchone()
```

See the last paragraph of the documentation on [tuples and sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) for information about sequence unpacking